# Date filter for Facebook Messenger conversation using GraphAPI

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Graph API to read Messenger chat messages using the link below:
[https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me?fields=conversations{id,messages{id,created_time,message,from}}](https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me?fields=conversations%7Bid,messages%7Bid,created_time,message,from%7D%7D)

As a conversation may have many messages that are already downloaded. I have tried using since but it doesn't work.

Is there any way that can add a date filter on it so that I only read new messages from a specific time?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations#limitations: _“Time-based pagination is not available for the conversations endpoint.”_

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **message_count**

```
/me?fields=conversations{messages{message,from,created_time,to},message_count}
```

Then you can determine the latest message in and you can perform your new messages.